# Unclear whether a Spark issue has been resolved in any Spark release

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, data-conversion

I'm using AWS Glue 4, which runs on Spark 3.3.0.
I'm hampered by the following issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25177

Which can be best summarized as follows:

> If scale of decimal type value is > 6 , a zero (0) value will be shown/output in scientific notation and hence, when > the dataframe output is saved to external database, it fails due to scientific notation on "0" values.

Reproducible as follows:

```
spark.sql("create table test (a decimal(10,7), b decimal(10,6), c decimal(10,8))")
spark.sql("insert into test values(0, 0,0)")
spark.sql("insert into test values(1, 1, 1)")
spark.table("test").show()
+---------+--------+----------+
|        a|       b|         c|
+---------+--------+----------+
|     0E-7|0.000000|      0E-8| //If scale > 6, zero is displayed in scientific notation
|1.0000000|1.000000|1.00000000|
+---------+--------+----------+
```

I've tested this on AWS Glue 4 (which runs Spark 3.3.0), but it is not fixed there.

Would anyone know if this associated Spark pull request
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22171
actually ever made it into a Spark release? From the pull request I can see that the fix made it into master. But I'm not certain if that means it ever got released.

Thanks in advance for your help.

PS: a workable workaround is suggested here: https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D53f00001lLNxuCAG/dataframe-cast-string-to-decimal-when-encountering-zeros-returns-oe16

Comment: it is not merged. just closed.

Answer (score 0):

@Lamanus confirmed that the issue is just closed, and not solved.